# Am I misunderstanding the definition of a connection in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In the following paragraph, taken from a Quora question, what exactly is the connection being made here? It’s my understanding that for a connection it has to be between two things, but I don’t see what two things are being connected here or what specifically is the connection.

> Another connection I've made is broad and widely applicable. When a field has lots of experts, the field is actually poorly understood and the current best thinking is probably wrong. The fact that there are so many experts on business, politics, economics, diet, nutrition and health is a strong indication that this subject matter is not well understood. When things are well understood you don't need many experts. You just need reference material.

httlps://www.quora.com/As-someone-with-a-high-IQ-what-are-some-connections-that-you-see-that-others-have-missed

Comment: The "connection" is a synaptic connection in his brain.  It means he's had an interesting thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Connection" isn't the ideal word for this context, but it works casually. (However, this wording likely would not have been allowed in a peer reviewed or edited publication.) Better wordings would be "Another conclusion I've come to..." or "Another insight I've had...". But loosely, you can think of it as "connecting facts". Previously this author perceived that: 1) There were many experts in the field of nutrition; and 2) We don't actually seem to understand nutrition very well. How can these facts coexist? Intuitively, they seem contradictory. But the author was able to connect those statements using the explanation that number of experts is not actually an indicator that a field is well understood. Etymologically, to "connect" means to ["tie together"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/connect#etymonline_v_28645) — Think of these connections as "tying together facts". That said, you are correct that it is an odd use.